# Ubuntu apt-update

Tags: apt, updates, mirrors

While updating the repository using `apt update`, I'm getting this error and I think the issue is on the **mirror**

```
E: Failed to fetch https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu-ports/dists/mantic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 103.152.178.194 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Your URL mentions UBUNTU-PORTS, meaning a non *amd64* (or non *i386*) package will be available; yet you appear to be trying to download an AMD64 binary (*which isn't a PORT*).  Your sources need correction as someone has corrupted them.

Answer (score 1):

More or less, quite simply the repository isn't there.

The [front page](https://mirror.nishi.network) suggests that the repo owner split up the common i386 and AMD64 repositories, and the other ports into seperate directory trees

You *should* be using `https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu` not `https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu-ports` for AMD64 clients

Comment: How to solve it... i don't know can explain

Comment: Try replacing ANYWHERE where it says "ubuntu-ports" with ubuntu. - then apt update then apt upgrade

Comment: Thank you,It worked.